# How to use react-hook-form dynamic resolver validation?

Tags: validation, dynamic, schema, react-hook-form, resolver

I'm using react-hook-form for form submitting, and I need to make the validation work dynamically.
For example, in the form, the category has three options: 'firstCateogory', 'secondCategory', 'thirdCategory'.

If the user chooses the category "firstCategory", the schema should be dynamically changed: the version input should be changed from 'Yup.string().nullable()' to 'Yup.string().nullable().required('Version is required')', required while the other two category options don't have the version required validation.

```
 const Schema = Yup.object().shape({
        category: Yup.string().nullable().required('Category is required'),
        title: Yup.string().nullable().required('Title is required'),
        version: Yup.string().nullable()
    });

 const DynamicSchema = Yup.object().shape({
        category: Yup.string().nullable().required('Category is required'),
        title: Yup.string().nullable().required('Title is required'),
        version: Yup.string().nullable().required('Version is required')
    });


 const methods = useForm({
     resolver: yupResolver(Schema),
     defaultValues,
    });

const {
        getValues,
        setValue,
        watch,
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { isSubmitting },
    } = methods;

...

return (
    <FormProvider methods={methods} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
       <RHFSelect
            name="category"
            label="Category">
           {CATEGORY.map((item) => (
                        <MenuItem >
                            {item.label}
                        </MenuItem>
                    ))}
                </RHFSelect>

          {watch('category') === 'firstCategory' && (
                    <RHFTextField
                        name="version"
                        label="Version"
                    />
                )}
```

I've read a lot of things about this issue, but nothing really helped. In this following code, I've tried to make the resolver dynamically change, but I couldn't use watch method here, it is not defined yet.

```
     resolver: yupResolver(Schema), // resolver: watch('category') === 'firstCategory' ? yupResolver(Schema) : yupResolver(DynamicSchema)
     defaultValues,
    });
```

Is there a way to use the resolver dynamically change?

---

**This is the code that I've changed based on your answer.**

```
import {Controller, useForm} from 'react-hook-form';

const Schema = Yup.object().shape({
        category: Yup.string().nullable().required('Category is required'),
        title: Yup.string().nullable().required('Title is required'),
        version: Yup.string().when('category', (value) => {
            if (value[0] === 'category1') {
                return Yup.string().required('Version is required')
            } else if (value[0] === 'category2' || value[0] === 'category3') {
                return Yup.string().nullable()
            }
        }),
    });

 const {
            getValues,
            setValue,
            watch,
            handleSubmit,
            control,
            formState: { isSubmitting, errors },
        } = useForm({
            resolver: yupResolver(Schema),
            defaultValues,
        });

...

return (
 <FormProvider onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
       <FormControl>
             <Controller
                 name="category"
                 control={control}
                 render={({field}) => (
                     <RHFSelect
                         {...field}
                         label={<EssentialLabel text="Category" />}
                      >
                           {CATEGORY_LIST.map((item) => (
                                <MenuItem key={item.code}
                                          value={item.code}
                                          onClick={() =>
                                             field.onChange(item)
                                          }>
                                        {item.label}
                                </MenuItem>
                             ))}
                         </RHFSelect>
                    )}
                 />
        </FormControl>
</FormProvider>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve dynamic validation there is no need for two separate schemas, you can implement a single schema and dynamically apply validation rules based on the field value and using when. Below I am giving my code of how I performed dynamic validation

```
import React from 'react';
import * as yup from 'yup';
import { FormControl, Menu, MenuButton, MenuItem, MenuList, FormLabel, Input, Button, Box } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';

const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  category: yup.string().nullable().required('Category is required'),
  title: yup.string().nullable().required('Title is required'),
  version: yup.string().when('category', (value)=>{
    if(value[0] === "category2" || value[0] === "category3"){
        return yup.string().nullable()
    }else{
        return yup.string().required('Version is required')
    }
  })
});

function YupValidation() {
  const categoryList = ["category1", "category2", "category3"];
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      category: "",
      title: "",
      version: ""
    },
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
  });

  const onSubmit = async(data) => {
    console.log("successfully submitted",data);
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <FormControl>
        <FormLabel mt="1rem">
          Category <span style={{ color: "red" }}>*</span>
        </FormLabel>
        <Controller
          name="category"
          control={control}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <Menu>
              <MenuButton as={Button}>
                {field.value ? field.value : "Select Category"}
              </MenuButton>
              <MenuList>
                {categoryList.map((item, index) => (
                  <MenuItem key={index} onClick={() => field.onChange(item)}>{item}</MenuItem>
                ))}
              </MenuList>
            </Menu>
          )}
        />
        {errors.category && (
          <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors.category.message}</p>
        )}
      </FormControl>
      <FormControl>
        <FormLabel mt="1rem">
          Title <span style={{ color: "red" }}>*</span>
        </FormLabel>
        <Controller
          name="title"
          control={control}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <Input {...field} />
          )}
        />
        {errors.title && (
          <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors.title.message}</p>
        )}
      </FormControl>
      <FormControl>
        <FormLabel mt="1rem">
          Version 
        </FormLabel>
        <Controller
          name="version"
          control={control}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <Input {...field} />
          )}
        />
        {errors.version && (
          <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors.version.message}</p>
        )}
      </FormControl>
      <Box display="flex" justifyContent="center">
        <Button
          type="submit"
          width="20rem"
          color="white"
          mb="2rem"
          mt="2rem"
          bgColor="blue"
        >
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Box>
    </form>
  )
}

export default YupValidation;
```

Comment: Hello, thanks so much for your answer. I've tried to use your code, but I got this error. 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_names')' . The error occurs at useController, Controller, and it looks like some name doesn't match when using the controller, but I couldn't find what the problem is. Do you have any idea why this error occurs?
Here is how I changed my code.

Comment: I've added the new code above in the question, you could find it after 'This is the code that I've changed based on your answer.'

Comment: I think the error is because of you are using onSubmit in FormProvider tag we can't directly use onSubmit in FormProvider. You can use it like this provide control to FormProvider and onSubmit in form tag <FormProvider {...control}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>

Comment: Hello, actually, I'm using onSubmit in FormProvider tag directly in other components, so I think something else is the problem but I couldn't solve it yet . Thanks for your reply, I would leave a comment when I solve it. Have a nice day !